Hydration Fail NextJS 15 and Styled Components
I keep getting the hydration failed error when using NextJS v15 and StyledComponents (see image attached).
Here is the repo if anyone wants to check :
https://github.com/mr-greg/portfolio-v2
I have tried adding the following _document.js :
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}


and numerous other solution I could find, but nothing worked.
If anyone has any idea or encountered this issue without me having to not use styled component, that would be great.
Thanks in advance !
New to StackOverflow and cannot post images, so here is a copy paste of the error message from NextJS on the front-end localhost :
Console Error

Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client. As a result this tree will be regenerated on the client. This can happen if a SSR-ed Client Component used

- A server/client branch `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`.
- Variable input such as `Date.now()` or `Math.random()` which changes each time it's called.
- Date formatting in a user's locale which doesn't match the server.
- External changing data without sending a snapshot of it along with the HTML.
- Invalid HTML tag nesting.

It can also happen if the client has a browser extension installed which messes with the HTML before React loaded.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error


+ className="sc-dntaoT kwpLBb"
- className="sc-blHHSb mSnUo"
+ className="sc-ivxoEo iaVHeu"
- className="sc-gtLWhw fYVTpf"
+ className="sc-gtLWhw jcqRrQ"
- className="sc-egkSDF iVPGTD"
+ className="sc-egkSDF bnNXfG"
- className="sc-fAUdSK dGZodg"
+ className="sc-fAUdSK cxJxcn"
- className="sc-dntaoT uKlRd"
+ className="sc-fAUdSK cxJxcn"
- className="sc-dntaoT uKlRd"
+ className="sc-fAUdSK cxJxcn"

etc...
